# How do I sum over multiple criteria in T-SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to improve on my very basic SQL querying skills and am using the AdventureWorks2012 sample database in SQL Server 2012. I have used `SUM() OVER(PARTITION BY)` like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    SUM(SubTotal) OVER (PARTITION BY CustomerID), CustomerID
FROM 
    Sales.SalesOrderHeader
```

To get the total sales value for each customer, however I'd like to sum the `SubTotal` by customer & year using `YEAR(OrderDate)` to extract just the year portion of the order date.

Firstly it appears that I can't use the year portion of the order date to sum by year independently of customer so this approach isn't going to work anyhow.

Secondly I can't see any way to use multiple partition criteria.

I suspect that my inexperience is leading me to think about this in the wrong way so a theoretical approach would be as useful as a specific solution.

I guess I'm looking for something that is functionally similar to Excel's `SUMIFS()` function

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, the correct way to write your query is:

```
SELECT CustomerID, SUM(SubTotal)
FROM Sales.SalesOrderHeader
GROUP BY CustomerID;
```

Using `SELECT DISTINCT` with window functions is clever.  But, it overcomplicates the query, can have poorer performance, and is confusing to anyone reading it.

To get the information by year (for each customer), just add that to the `SELECT` and `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT CustomerID, YEAR(OrderDate) as yyyy, SUM(SubTotal)
FROM Sales.SalesOrderHeader
GROUP BY CustomerID, YEAR(OrderDate)
ORDER BY CustomerId, yyyy;
```

If you actually want to get separate rows with subtotals, then study up on `GROUPING SETS` and `ROLLUP`.  These are options to the `GROUP BY`.

Comment: Thank you Gordon, very much appreciated - guess I'm trying to run before I can walk! I wasn't aware of those extensions to standard GROUP BY and will look into them in more depth, although your code appears to do what I want as is

Answer (score 1):

You should use `group by` instead of `PARTITION BY` whenever you need an aggregate (`sum/count/max`) against a specific column like (customerid) as following

```
select customerId, sum(subTotal)
FROM sales.salesOrderHeader
group by customerId
```

**Edit** : including missing requirement of date (response to comment)

If you want calculation against more than one column, you still can do it same way. Just add the `date` in group by clause as `group by customerId, saleDate`

```
select customerId, sum(subTotal)
,saleDate //=> you can miss it (date) from selection if you want to
FROM sales.salesOrderHeader
group by customerId, saleDate
```

Comment: Thanks for the prompt response Sami but that misses my requirement for summing according to date and customer ID. I do get your point about GROUP BY and will explore that further to improve my (limited!) understanding